# What does the word QUOTE do in MS Access VBA?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have been reviewing a sample MS Access database that generates a nice calendar. Within the code I see the use of the actual word "QUOTE" several times and I can't find any information as to what it actually does. 
Here is a sample:

```
(" _& QUOTE & Me.txtSubject & QUOTE & ", " _
    & QUOTE & Me.txtLocation & QUOTE & ", " _
    & "#" & Format(vNewStart, "yyyy/m/d hh:nn") & "#, " _
    & "#" & Format(vNewEnd, "yyyy/m/d hh:nn") & "#, " _
    & QUOTE & Me.txtNotes & QUOTE & ")"
```

What is the word QUOTE doing here?

Comment: It's not part of Access. I'd guess it's a variable or constant declared somewhere in the code you're reading that is being used to prevent the problems with embedded quote characters when concatenating strings, like `""'"" & somevalue & ""'""` that you see often.

Comment: Thank you Ken, that was it. It's a constant that was declared elsewhere in the project.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Ken's comment I found that it's a constant declared earlier in the code. I should of seen that before asking. Here is the declaration:

```
Public Const QUOTE = """"    'Used in SQL strings where the ' char may be used in text strings
```

Comment: Note: put the cursor in any constant or variable and press Shift+F2, it will take you to its definition.